# Mallocing char* with same length as another char* causes it become a copy?

Tags: c, gcc

I am currently trying to write a simple C program that creates a struct with a char* field and assigns it to have the same value as argv[1]. I then want to create another char* with the same length as argv[1], but for some reason the data inside already contains the same value as argv[1]. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct example{
    char *str;
};

struct example* create(char *s){
    struct example *p = (struct example*)malloc(sizeof(struct example));
    char * copy = (char*)malloc(strlen(s));
    strcpy(copy, s);
    p->str = copy;
    free(copy);
    return p;
}

void new_char(struct example * t){
    printf("original: %s\n", t->str);
    char *w = (char *)malloc(strlen(t->str));
    printf("why is this a copy? %s\n", w);
    free(w);
}

void clean(struct example *t){
    free(t);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct example * p = create(argv[1]);
    new_char(p);
    clean(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Then when I compile and run this program using GCC 6.1, I get this out put

```
> gcc -Wall -g -o test test.c
> ./test "test value here"
> original: test value here
> why is this a copy? test value here
```

Comment: Your code exhibits undefined behaviour. You are not allowed to access `copy` after calling `free` on it and that's what you do.

Comment: Also `malloc`ing `strlen` characters doesn't leave extra for the null-terminator added by `strcpy`.

Comment: `malloc(strlen(s));` --> `malloc(strlen(s) + 1);`

Comment: Don't think of `malloc()` and `free()` as acting on the pointer variable -- they allocate/free blocks of memory, that are separate from the pointer variable itself... the pointer variable is just used to hold the address so you know where to find it.  You don't free the block when you're done with the pointer variable you put the `malloc()` result in -- you free it when you're done with the block of memory you `malloc()`ed (though you need to keep its address *somewhere* until then).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this code is wrong

```
struct example* create(char *s){
    struct example *p = (struct example*)malloc(sizeof(struct example));
    char * copy = (char*)malloc(strlen(s));
    strcpy(copy, s);
    p->str = copy;
    free(copy);
    return p;
}
```

first you need to allocate strlen + 1

Second you cannot free 'copy' here, p->str points at it, you now have a dangling pointer. To copy and malloc use strdup http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup

```
struct example* create(char *s){
    struct example *p = (struct example*)malloc(sizeof(struct example));
    p->str = strdup(s);
    return p;
}
```

The reason you got the same string is because you released your string back to the heap and then got it back again when you called malloc, this is purely luck, another time you might crash, get garbage,...

Comment: would it also be valid to instead of freeing copy in the create() function, free it the clean() method like this:
free(t->str);

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do. you need to free the string when you dont need it anymore. If you free it too early you will get odd behavior including crashing and corruption. If you free it too late you have a memory leak - welcome to C

Comment: Ah, ok that makes sense. Also for the p->str = strdup(s); In my clean() function, would I also need to free(p->str); or does freeing p, take care of that for me?

Comment: in c nothing happens by magic, freeing p does not free anything that p points at, it doesnt know that you dont have another pointer somewhere pointing at the same string. But in your case you should go free(p->str); free(p); cos we know that p->str is a 'private' copy

Answer (score 2):

Look at this lines:

```
char * copy = (char*)malloc(strlen(s));
...
p->str = copy;
free(copy);
return p;
```

You alloc a block of memory, initialize it, store a pointer to it in your structure, and then free it! From that `free()` on, the `p->str` pointer points to freed memory, that is memory that must not be used.

What happens next? You do another:

```
char *w = (char *)malloc(strlen(t->str));
```

which, by chance, gets get memory just freed from the previous code, and since `malloc()` *does not* initialize the returned memory in any way, it happens to have the same string you just used.

What you see is actually garbage (uninitialized memory) that just happens to take the shape of a recent used text.

Summing up, your code has three problems:

1. You free the string you are returning in `create()`
2. You do not free the string in `clean()` before freeing the struct.
3. You try to print an uninitialized chunk of memory and wonder what the garbage means.

Answer (score 2):

Hrre is the problem:

```
char * copy = (char*)malloc(strlen(s));
strcpy(copy, s);
p->str = copy;
free(copy);
```

You allocated a copy of original string and immediately free it.

```
char *w = (char *)malloc(strlen(t->str));
```

This line reuses previously freed memory and that's why you get the same content - the pointer is the same.

Note this happens in very simple scenarios and is specific to c library you use.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc` doesn't initialize the memory it allocates. The second call to `malloc` happened to assign the same block of memory the first call to `malloc` has allocated (seeing as it had become unallocated when you called `free`). You cannot count on this.

Errors:

- You need to allocate space for the NUL too. `malloc(strlen(s))` should be `malloc(strlen(s)+1)`.
- You may not access unallocated memory, as you when you print `t->str` and when you try to find its length. You probably didn't mean to deallocate it. `free(copy);` should be moved to `clean` as `free(t->str);`.
- Casting the value returned by `malloc` is necessary in C++, but is needless in C.

Tips:

- `strdup` is a convenient shortcut for `strlen`+`malloc`+`strcpy`.
- If you write

  ```
  typedef struct { ... } example;
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  struct example { ... };
  ```

  you can use `example` instead of `struct example`.

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct {
    char *str;
} example;

example* create(char *s){
    example *p = malloc(sizeof(example));
    p->str = strdup(s);
    return p;
}

void new_char(example * t){
    printf("original: %s\n", t->str);
    char *w = strdup(t->str);
    printf("%s\n", w);  // Prints uninitialized memory.
    free(w);
}

void clean(example *t){
    free(t->str);
    free(t);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    example * p = create(argv[1]);
    new_char(p);
    clean(p);
    return 0;
}
```